# Раскодировать и кодировка пакета

Tags: java, netty

Использую netty.
Имеется такой код.

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
public class ServerAdapterInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new Encoder());//Кодирует
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new Decoder());//Расшифровывает

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerAdapterHandler());// ServerAdapterHandler() будет принимать все пакеты от клиентов.
    }
}
```

(см. https://hastebin.com/fatubasugo.scala)

Создал свои 2 класса.
Encoder и Decoder.

Они оба одинаковы:

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Packet;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder;

public class Encoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Packet> {

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Packet packet, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

(см. https://hastebin.com/pajirogawu.scala)

Проблема в том что я не понимаю как я могу закодировать и раскодировать пакет который получу от клиента или сервера.

Смотрел стрингой кодер декодер но мало чего понял.
Разьясните мне пожалуйста =) как правильно кодировать и разкодировать пакеты принятые клиентом или сервером.

Скиньте пару сайтиков где на русском написаны простейшие примеры.

Comment: Для начала: вы знаете структуру пакета, который получите от сервера ил пошлете с клиента?

Comment: Вынужден вас расстроить, пары сайтиков с примерами нет не только на русском, но и на английском. Всё, что есть - это _Hello World_ на официальном сайте, javadoc-описание API там же и книга на английском "Netty In Action", доходчивость и содержательность которой лучше всего описывается [старой шуткой про сову](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLStI.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Если не знаете, как написать свой качественный кодек, можете использовать готовые кодеки, например, - Google Protobuf, который поддерживает netty. По [этой](https://github.com/lohitvijayarenu/netty-protobuf/tree/master/src/main/java/org/demo/nettyprotobuf) ссылке можете посмотреть пример.
Так же советую почитать официальное описание [тут](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial).

Объясню вкратце, чтобы было легче разобраться, что вам придется сделать, чтобы интегрировать этот кодек:

1.Добавить в ChannelPipeline готовые классы Protobuf(вместо ваших encoder и decoder):

```
p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
p.addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Ваш.protoОбъект.getDefaultInstance()));

p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
p.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());
```

2.Создать .proto и скомпилировать его в класс (это объект, который будет сжиматься для передачи и разжиматься при получении, может называться, например, message). Подробнее по ссылкам, что я дал.

Всё, готово, далее просто включаете в ChannelPipeline ваш ChannerHandler с логикой, где вы будете использовать уже свой объект, который описали в .proto.

Если что-то не понятно, можете задавать вопросы.